# problem using Turtlebot Interactive Markers

Tags: ros, rviz, turtlebot, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to use interactive markers to move the turtlebot using Ros Electric version.
The connexion with the turtlebot seems ok. The turtlebot service is running on the laptop. The dashboard is all green!!

I'm following the "TurtleBot Teleoperation Using Interactive Markers" tutorial. When I click on "interact" button on rviz, the interactive markers appear. But when I click on them to move the robot, only the camera moves. It's like I didn't change mode.

Has someone an idea of what is going wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33112/problem-using-turtlebot-interactive-markers/) by [Barriere Mickael](https://answers.ros.org/users/2293/barriere-mickael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest using "rostopic echo /cmd_vel" on the TurtleBot netbook to verify that when you're interacting, the messages are being received by the netbook. If they're not, you may need to make sure ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME are set properly on the machine running rviz. (check [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) for more information)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0